# Unable to update or select value from SQLite in android Application

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

i'm working on android application and i'm using  Sqlite db and i created bunch of methods to add tables and insert and all of them are working correctly except of 2 methods

the first is Update methods the value of field to 1

```
public void UnlockNextLevel(String lvlname ,int num){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SchemClass.LetsCode2.COLUMN_NAME_LEVELSTATUS,num);
    db.update(SchemClass.LetsCode2.SECOND_TABLE ,cv, SchemClass.LetsCode2.COLUMN_NAME_LevelName +" = "+lvlname,null );
}
```

and when i run it , it causes a run time exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a96653.LetsCode, PID: 3392
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Ploto (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE LEVEL SET LevelStatus=? WHERE LevelName =  Ploto
```

The other method is select method from db :

```
public int returnQuestionAnswer (int Qnum){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   int lnum=100;
   String query = "SELECT "+SchemClass.LetsCode2.COLUMN_NAME_QANSWER +" FROM "+SchemClass.LetsCode2.TABLE_AUESTION +" WHERE "+SchemClass.LetsCode2.COLUMN_NAME_QNUM +" = "+Qnum;
   Cursor recordSet=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    recordSet.moveToFirst();

    while (!recordSet.isAfterLast()){
        lnum=recordSet.getInt(recordSet.getColumnIndex(SchemClass.LetsCode2.COLUMN_NAME_QANSWER));
    }
    db.close();

   return lnum;
}
```

When i want to display the integer value in textView it causes runtime exception

The last Exception i wasn't able to post it so i'll post it here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' 
on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
```

Comment: The last Exception i wasn't able to post it so i'll post it here java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue 1

The update is failing because the value to be compared is enclosed in quotes and is therefore considered as an identifier (column name in this case), rather than a literal value. To fix this use :-

```
db.update(SchemClass.LetsCode2.SECOND_TABLE ,cv, SchemClass.LetsCode2.COLUMN_NAME_LevelName +" = '"+lvlname + "'",null );
```

Or better still use :-

```
db.update(SchemClass.LetsCode2.SECOND_TABLE ,cv, SchemClass.LetsCode2.COLUMN_NAME_LevelName +"=?",new String[]{lvlname} );
```

- using the **?** placeholder in conjunction with an argument is considered better as it protects against SQL Injection and automatically encloses the value ensuring that it is treated as a literal rather than an identifier.

## Issue 2

There is insufficient information to determine the second issue but in all likelihood the Context is null and that this is because you have something like

```
your_DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

in the activity's class definition, when you should be declaring the the DatabaseHelper object and then instantiating it in the **onCreate** method

e.g. something like

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDBHlpr;
    //DatabaseHelper myDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this); <<<<<<<<<< NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this); //<<<<<<<<< instantiates the DatabaseHelper Object
    }
}
```

- Note names of objects/activity would have to be changed according to your code.
- You may not have AppCompActivity, this has been used for demonstration but the same principle applies.

Comment: I did these changes and i did not cause run time exception but the update method  it did not reflect in the database

Comment: Check the value returned by the **update** method if it's 1 or more then rows are being update, if not then there isn't a row with the value **Ploto** assuming that is the value that lvlname resolves to.

Comment: @AlbtoulAlmuhanna that's good, could you tick the answer if you believe that the answer helped you solve the problem.